# extract lines of a file each day in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I have a file with 20.000.000 lines and each day to this file is added or removed some lines and i need do a crontab, i need each day obtain 9 files of 50.000 lines.

For example:

```
BigFile is my file with 20.000.000 lines.
```

And i need generate 9 files, the first file with the line 1 to 50000, the second file with the line 50001 to 100000, the third file the line 100001 to 150000 `. . .`

I can't do a split the first time because my file change all days, and the second problem that i have is if the first time i obtain my 9 files the second day i need continue with last line use.

For example the first day i use 450.000 lines, then the second day i need the first line with the line 450001 to 500000, and the third day i need use the 900001 for my first file.

The split not works because if i use a split the first time, the files change, then the files that i have do not work for the second day

Can you help me?

Comment: so you need the last 450.000 lines from the file split to 9 files. right?

Comment: or... simply... reformulate the question. not very clear, what you really want, because if you split by 50k lines, you can use those 9 files what want and delete the remaining... so probably you want something other - simply write a better question.

Comment: Give up the requirement to allow the file to grow. Move the file aside, allow new content to accumulate for tomorrow in a new file. Now splitting today's content from a basically static file is a simple matter.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `split` command ([manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/split)).

For example:

```
$ split -l 50000 /path/to/bigfile
```

Comment: The problem is that if i use the split the first time, my file change each day.

Comment: @AlexanderOvalle It looks like my answer won't help then.  You have a pretty complex problem to solve.